# How to use MEF Inherited Export & MetaData?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, mef

I have an interface:

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(IMetric))]
public interface IMetric { ... }
```

I have a Meta attribute interface:

```
 public interface IMetricAttribute { ... }
```

and an attribute that implements it:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MetricAttribute : ExportAttribute, IMetricAttribute {
    public string MetricName { get; set; }
    public string MetricDescription { get; set; }

    public MetricAttribute(string name, string description)
        : base(typeof(MetricAttribute)) {
        this.MetricName = name;
        this.MetricDescription = description;
    }
}
```

I then have two classes:

```
[Metric("MetricA","MetricA")]
public class MetricA: IMetric { ... }

[Export(typeof(IMetric))] <<<< THIS IS IMPORTANT
[Metric("MetricB", "MetricB")]
public class MetricB: IMetric { ... }
```

I then try to import the metrics ( i can see both in the cataloge)

The following returns be MetricA AND MetricB

```
var metrics = compositionContainer.GetExports<IMetric>();
```

However the following returns ONLY MetricB and NOT MetricA

```
var metrics = compositionContainer.GetExports<IMetric, IMetricAttribute>();
```

**any idea why?**

(note the duplicate export on MetricB (it already has it from implementing IMetric))

thanks

David

Comment: +1 Interesting question, looking forward to see the answer. Wouldn't it be possible to work around this issue by the following: Instead of using `InheritedExport` on `IMetric` you could use only the `MetricAttribute` as you anyway have to declare it on your deriving types. At `MetricAttribute` ctor you could call `base(typeof(IMetric))`. You haven't provided further information on the `MetricAttribute` implementation, maybe you're already doing this there.

Comment: @ba_friend - thanks I've tried your suggestion which worked nicely though I'm not quite sure why? I'm still interested to find out why the original code didn't work

Comment: Me either, i would like to try it myself but thats not possible at the moment.

Comment: Came from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF?msg=4859907#xx4859907xx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First time I've seen this behaviour, but from what I can understand, metadata is generated per-export at the type level. So, given:

```
[Metric("MetricA", "MetricA")]
public class MetricA : IMetric
{

}
```

You have two exports for this type. You have the export of `MetricA` which is implictly provided by your `MetricAttribute`, and you have the inherited export for `IMetric` provided by the `InheritedExport(typeof(IMetric))` attribute on your interface.

If you look at the container, you'll notice two exports defined for `MetricA`. Here is the first, with its metadata:

[image]

And here is the second:

[image]

You'll notice that the metadata is done on the export of `MetricA`, not the inherited export. If I added a further export, lets say `[Export("test")]` to `MetricA`, you get another export definition, with the same metadata items for `MetricName` and `MetricDescription` for the contract named "test". This shows you that as the type is analysed, the export attribute is identified, and the export definition that is created includes the metadata specified at the same level in the abstraction tree.

The easiest way to do what you want, is to drop out the `InheritedExport`, and modify your definition of your `MetricAttribute` to:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false), MetadataAttribute]
public class MetricAttribute : ExportAttribute, IMetricAttribute
{
    public MetricAttribute(string name, string description)
        : base(typeof(IMetric))
    {
        this.MetricName = name;
        this.MetricDescription = description;
    }

    public string MetricName { get; private set; }
    public string MetricDescription { get; private set; }

}
```

Where you then pass in `typeof(IMetric)` to the base `ExportAttribute` constructor. You then correctly get the two exports for `GetExports<IMetric>()` and `GetExports<IMetric, IMetricAttribute>()`.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I think i see what you mean - to summarise: the problem is that metadata is linked to exports, however the inheritedexport doesn't seem to link to the meta data on implemented classes (a strange design decision!). One solution is then as ba_friend said to get the attribute to do an export so that the export and the metadata are linked.  I will accept your answer though i do wonder whether it is possible to use inherited export together with metadata - but maybe that is another question i should post! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and found a differen solution which worked fine for me:
I just added metadata to the interface!

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(IMetric))]
[Metric("name","description")]
public interface IMetric { ... }
```

You can leave the fields blank or use null as default, but it is important to specify the Metadata here.
Then you specify your classes without export attribute:

```
[Metric("MetricA")]
public class MetricA: IMetric { ... }
```

Be aware that you can can specify just one metadata, but the second one won't be `description` in this case, it will be `null`! So the metadata in the interface are NOT default values.
All in all this worked for me and I can use InheritedExport with my metadata :-)

Comment: You can get around the "just one metadata" problem by using attributes derived from MetadataAttribute. But they work only when applied to the final exported class; that is, they cannot be inherited - stupid design decision.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify on Matthew answer:

When you are defining custom metadata attribute class `MetricAttribute` and inheriting from `ExportAttribute`, you are essentially adding `[Export]` attribute to all classes that you decorate with your `[Metric]` attribute. This means that you don't need `[InheritedExport]` attribute on the interface anymore as it just creates separate export definition without any metadata.

If you want to create a more reusable metadata attribute, you can expose `ExportAttribute` constructor parameters in your `MetricAttribute` as follows:

```
public MetricAttribute(Type contractType, string name, string description)
    : base(contractType)
{
    this.MetricName = name;
    this.MetricDescription = description;
}
```

By introducing `contractType` variable you can now supplement your definition of

```
[Export(typeof(IMetric))]
[Metric("MetricB", "MetricB")]
public class MetricB: IMetric { ... }
```

with:

```
[Metric(typeof(IMetric), "MetricB", "MetricB")]
public class MetricB: IMetric { ... }
```